# Cannot display second image on imageview fetch from drawable in android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am new to android and I am fetching two different image from drawable folder on two different button click on different imageview. second image cannot be displayed in second imageview on button click.

```
            enter code here


                    tool1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tool11);
                    tool2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tool12);
                    tool1.setOnClickListener(this);
                    tool2.setOnClickListener(this);
     case R.id.tool11://this is my button onclicklistener
                            d= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy);//drawable
                            myImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                            myImage1 .setImageResource(R.drawable.happy);
                            myBitmap1 = Bitmap Factory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                                    R.drawable.happy);
                   case R.id.tool12:
        d1= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cool);
                            myImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                            myImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cool);
                            myBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                                    R.drawable.cool);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Please ans my question

Comment: I have added break then also not working it is force closed when I click on tool12

Answer (score 1):

Add `break;` at the end of each select case.

Comment: I have added break then also not working it is force closed when I click on tool12.

Comment: What is the Logcat errors? Please also share the entire method including your code

Answer (score 0):

as you used switch case blocks

```
case R.id.tool1:
// functionality
  Break;
case R.id.tool2:
 //functionality
Break;
```

use Break after case.

Comment: I have added but then also not it is force closed when i clicked on tool12.

Comment: In your code you had written myBitmap1,myBitmap2 where are you using these.

Comment: Bitmap mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth() ,myBitmap.getHeight(),myBitmap.getConfig());
  
   mCanvas = new Canvas(mBackground);

  
   mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap ,new Matrix(), null);
   mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1,x-dx,y-dy, null);
   mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap2,x-dx,y-dy, null);